# query.findInbackGround from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a problem in my project when i download data from parse with findinbackground method. So look at my code (loadAllData method() and LoadDataAsyncTask) . I wanna loaddata in this Activity and i will use it in different activity but when i call my onjects in different activity it is null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find);

    new LoadDataAsynceTask().execute();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), FRAGMENT_HOME_TAG);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private class LoadDataAsynceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
        loadAllData();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Toast.makeText(FindActivity.this,
                "Stastions "+stations.size()+
                "\nTimes "+stationTimes.size()+ 
                "\nTaxis "+taxis.size() 
                ,LENGTH_LONG).show(); // "Station 0 stationTime 0 Taxis 0"


    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...values) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
}

public void loadAllData() {
    ParseQuery<ThoiGianBusStation> query = new ParseQuery<>("ThoiGian");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ThoiGianBusStation>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ThoiGianBusStation> list, ParseException e) {
            for (ThoiGianBusStation i : list) {
                ThoiGianBusStation newTime = new ThoiGianBusStation();
                newTime.setPid(i.getPid());
                newTime.setPTime(i.getPTime());
                newTime.setPTimeId(i.getPTimeId());
                stationTimes.add(newTime);
            }
            Toast.makeText(FindActivity.this, "Times "+stationTimes.size() ,LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
// "statitonTimes 13"
        }
    });

    ParseQuery<ChuyenXe> query1 = new ParseQuery<>("BusStation");
    query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ChuyenXe>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ChuyenXe> list, ParseException e) {
            for (ChuyenXe chuyenXe : list) {
                ChuyenXe newXe = new ChuyenXe();
                newXe.setPHangxe(chuyenXe.getPHangxe());
                newXe.setPGotime(chuyenXe.getPGotime());
                newXe.setPTransforment(chuyenXe.getPTransforment());
                newXe.setPTram(chuyenXe.getPTram());
                newXe.setPGia(chuyenXe.getPGia());
                newXe.setPLoai(chuyenXe.getPLoai());
                newXe.setPNoidi(chuyenXe.getPNoidi());
                newXe.setPNoiden(chuyenXe.getPNoiden());
                newXe.setPSDT(chuyenXe.getPSDT());
                newXe.setPService(chuyenXe.getPService());
                newXe.setPXeID(chuyenXe.getPXeID());
                for (int i = 0; i < stationTimes.size(); i++) {
                    if (newXe.id == stationTimes.get(i).xe_id) {
                        newXe.addThoiGian(stationTimes.get(i).thoigian);
                    }
                }
                stations.add(newXe);
            }
            Toast.makeText(FindActivity.this, "Station " + stations.size(), LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
// "Station 4"
        }
    });

    ParseQuery<Taxi> query2 = new ParseQuery<>("Taxi");
    query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Taxi>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Taxi> list, ParseException e) {
            for (Taxi taxi : list){
                Taxi newTaxi = new Taxi();
                newTaxi.setPname(taxi.getPname());
                newTaxi.setPCost1(taxi.getPCost1());
                newTaxi.setPCost2(taxi.getPCost2());
                newTaxi.setPCost3(taxi.getPCost3());
                newTaxi.setPkv(taxi.getPkv());
                newTaxi.setPsdt(taxi.getPsdt());
                newTaxi.setPWay1(taxi.getPWay1());
                newTaxi.setPWay2(taxi.getPWay2());
                taxis.add(newTaxi);
            }
            Toast.makeText(FindActivity.this, "Taxis "+taxis.size() ,LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
// "Taxis 3"
        }
    });
}
```

}

ChuyenXe Class :

```
public class ChuyenXe extends ParseObject {
public int getPXeID(){
    return getInt("xe_id");
}
public void setPXeID(int noidi) {
    put("xe_id", noidi);
}

public String getPTransforment(){
    return getString("transforment");
}
public void setPTransforment(String noidi) {
    put("transforment", noidi);
}

public String getPTram(){
    return getString("tram_dung_chan");
}
public void setPTram(String noidi) {
    put("tram_dung_chan", noidi);
}

public String getPService(){
    return getString("services");
}
public void setPService(String noidi) {
    put("services", noidi);
}

public String getPSDT(){
    return getString("sdt");
}
public void setPSDT(String noidi) {
    put("sdt", noidi);
}

public String getPLoai(){
    return getString("loaixe");
}
public void setPLoai(String noidi) {
    put("loaixe", noidi);
}

public String getPHangxe(){
    return getString("hangxe");
}
public void setPHangxe(String noidi) {
    put("hangxe", noidi);
}

public String getPGotime(){
    return getString("go_time");
}
public void setPGotime(String noidi) {
    put("go_time", noidi);
}

public String getPGia(){
    return getString("gia");
}
public void setPGia(String noidi) {
    put("gia", noidi);
}

public String getPNoiden(){
    return getString("bendi");
}
public void setPNoiden(String noidi) {
    put("benden", noidi);
}

public String getPNoidi(){
    return getString("bendi");
}
public void setPNoidi(String noidi) {
    put("bendi", noidi);
}
```

ThoiGianBusStation class :

```
public class ThoiGianBusStation extends ParseObject{
 public int getPTimeId(){
    return getInt("time_id");
}
public void setPTimeId(int timeId) {
    put("time_id", timeId);
}

public int getPid(){
    return getInt("xe_id");
}
public void setPid(int name) {
    put("xe_id", name);
}

public String getPTime(){
    return getString("time");
}
public void setPTime(String time) {
    put("time", time);
}
```

Taxi class :

```
public class Taxi extends ParseObject{
public String getPname(){
    return getString("name");
}
public void setPname (String noidi) {
    put("name", noidi);
}

public String getPsdt(){
    return getString("sdt");
}
public void setPsdt (String noidi) {
    put("sdt", noidi);
}

public String getPkv(){
    return getString("khuvuc");
}
public void setPkv(String noidi) {
    put("khuvuc", noidi);
}

public int getPWay2(){
    return getInt("doan2");
}
public void setPWay2(int noidi) {
    put("doan2", noidi);
}

public int getPWay1(){
    return getInt("doan1");
}
public void setPWay1(int noidi) {
    put("doan1", noidi);
}

public int getPCost2(){
    return getInt("cost2");
}
public void setPCost2(int noidi) {
    put("cost2", noidi);
}
public int getPCost3(){
    return getInt("cost3");
}
public void setPCost3(int noidi) {
    put("cost3", noidi);
}
public int getPCost1(){
    return getInt("cost1");
}
public void setPCost1(int noidi) {
    put("cost1", noidi);
}
```

Comment: Please, post your objects classes too with your question,

Comment: see edit , do you understand my problem?

Comment: Is "Station 0 stationTime 0 Taxis 0" your first toast which is shown on your screen, before "Taxis 3" and others?

Comment: The problem is "findInBackground()", you should cnage it with "find()" because you did already an asnc task, "findInBackground()" creates  background thread, and when your asc task finished you do not get the result. You should change it with "find()".

Comment: if you use find() you don't need to use asynctask and your app will be stop many second while data is loaded.

Comment: But if the results are not returned you will not call your new activity.  You will always wait the data.

Comment: i used find() method and my app is very slow , so now i wanna change it to findinbackground for use Local DataStore

Comment: I also used Parse in my some projects. Free version is waiting min 2 sec to return results. You may get your results 10 by 10 if it is possible,   get only taxi result instead of 3of them if possible. Etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `findInBackground()`, you should change it with `find()` because you did already an asnc task, "findInBackground()" creates  new background thread, and when your asnc task finished, you probably won't get the results. Because your asnc task will not wait Parse background threads. You should change it with `find()`. Also Parse suggests `findInBackground()` in background tasks.